# Java multi client chat server

Tags: java, server, client, chat

I am new to Java programming and am trying to develop multi-client chat server.

following is my code:

```
package Server;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class server implements Runnable{

    private List<ServerClient> clients = new ArrayList<ServerClient>();

//private String UID;
private int port;
private ServerSocket socket;
private Thread run, manage, send, receive;
private boolean running = false;
public int i=0;

    public server(int port){
//      this.UID = UID;
        this.port = port;
        try {
            socket = new ServerSocket(port);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        run = new Thread(this, "Server");
        run.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        running = true;
        ManageClients();
        receive();
    }
    private void ManageClients(){
        manage = new Thread("Manage"){
            public void run(){
                while(running){
                    //managing
                }
            }
        };
        manage.start();
    }

    private void receive(){
        receive = new Thread("Receive"){
            public void run(){
                Socket S1 = null;
                try {
                    S1 = socket.accept();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                while(running){

/*                  byte [] data = new byte[1024];
                    DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length);
                    try {
                        socket.receive(packet);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    String string = new String(packet.getData());
                    System.out.println(string);*/
/*                  BufferedReader br = null;
                    try {
                        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(S1.getInputStream()));
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    try {
                        String string = br.readLine();
                        System.out.println(string);
                        process(string);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }*/
                    process(S1);
                    System.out.println(String.valueOf(i));
                    i++;
                }
            }
        };
        receive.start();
    }
    private void process(Socket S1){
        BufferedReader br = null;
        String string = "";
        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(S1.getInputStream()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            string = br.readLine();
            System.out.println(string);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(string.startsWith("/c/")){
            clients.add(new ServerClient("name", S1.getInetAddress(), S1.getPort(), "UID"));
        }
        else if(string.startsWith("/ip/")){
            //send ip address to raspberry
            System.out.println(string);
        }
        else if(string.startsWith("/r/")){
            //send relay command to relay
            System.out.println(string);
        }
    }
}
```

The server is accepting only one connection. If I try to connect another user the console does not show any output.

Can you please guide where I am going wrong.

Thank you

Comment: This is a very broad question which lacks specifics and detail.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the `accept` method multiple times... once for each client that wants to connect. Typically people do that on a separate thread in a `while` loop since the `accept` method is blocking.

In your code it seems like you are only calling `accept` once, and hence you will only get one client connection.

I would recommend that you change your code architecture here, but if you want to keep it the same, and you know how many clients will connect, then you could wrap your access to socket in a synchronization lock, and call your `receive` method once for each client.